# Views is not linking images to content for anonymous users in Commerce Kickstart

Tags: 7, views, users, media, commerce

I'm having this problem:

I'm using Commerce Kickstart 7.x-1.19 (also tryed on 2.x) and I'm trying to create a simple view to replace my homepage with a list of products, set the relation to the referenced prodcut etc. Everything is working as expected except for images that are not linked to content (node display) for anonymous users.

I know that the image formatter must be changed on Product Type -> Manage Display and not in the content type itself.

If I change a settings in the on the View I'm working, I can set any Image Style and is rendered as it should be, even Color box is working as expected for every user, but for some reason when I choose any Image Style and set Link image to: content this is not working, the image is not linking to the node.( Field title does link to the content)

I think this is a permissions issue because when I was setting this view I had this problem:  Views results empty for unprivileged user when using Relationship (https://drupal.org/node/1276450), I fixed that using the permission View any product of any type.

Any help or idea is very appreciated, this is driving me crazy...

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and was discussing this in an issue ticket for Drupal Commerce. Here is what I found:

> It is extremely unclear how to display products using Views. After
>   much googling, I had settled on creating a View displaying either
>   `CONTENT` or `COMMERCE PRODUCTS` displaying `FIELDS`. I would then add
>   a `RELATIONSHIP` to `CONTENT: REFERENCED PRODUCT`. This worked and it
>   was easy to add fields and get the output exactly how I wanted it. The
>   problem, and the reason I reopened this ticket, is that the `COMMERCE
>   PRODUCT: IMAGE` field would link to the admin display, not the product
>   display.
>
> The problem was what I chose to display when creating the View. First,
>   I updated Commerce Kickstart, which broke all my existing Views with a
>   SQL error. Then I installed a fresh Commerce Kickstart to test product
>   display views. There were numerous issues with the install, one which
>   broke the front page. No idea. But through testing the fresh install,
>   I stumbled across the idea to study the `COLLECTION` view that comes
>   with Commerce Kickstart. I noticed that it was displaying `PRODUCT
>   DISPLAY` content, and a field of `CONTENT: RENDERED ENTITY` with the
>   `PRODUCT LIST` view mode.
>
> Long story short, I discovered that by using Display Suite, I could
>   create custom view modes, which would be customized with the exact
>   fields I wanted to display. This had to be done on both the `CONTENT
>   TYPE` (product displays) and `VARIATION TYPES`. While `MANAGING
>   DISPLAY` for the type you are editing, select the tab at the bottom
>   labeled `CUSTOM DISPLAY SETTINGS` to enable the custom view mode made
>   in Display Suite. Then you can select the view mode for the content
>   types and change the fields available. Its a bit tricky to figure out
>   where to change what values (in `CONTENT TYPES` versus `VARIATION
>   TYPES`) but I'm sure most people can figure it out.
>
> After you create your `VIEW MODE`, create a new View that displays
>   `PRODUCT DISPLAY` items, not `CONTENT` or `COMMERCE PRODUCTS`. Then
>   make sure you are using `RENDERED ENTITY` either for the whole node or
>   in a field (where it will be listed `CONTENT: RENDERED ENTITY`). Under
>   the `RENDERED ENTITY` settings, select the `VIEW MODE` you created,
>   and viola! It outputs the fields you want AND links to the content not
>   the admin page. What it outputs will require some CSS styling, as
>   there are more default drupal styles applied to the rendered entity
>   than just plain fields. But that can be tweaked in the Views settings
>   themselves or by using Mothership Base theme.

This is from my original post is on [Drupal Commerce Issues](https://drupal.org/node/1970482#comment-7726873).

Hope this helps! :)